# How can I open only the clicked row data in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have defined a state variable called `fullText`.

`fullText` default value is `false`.

When Full Text is clicked, I want to reverse my state value and enable the text to be closed and opened. But when it is clicked, the texts in all rows in the table are opened, how can I make it row specific?

```
{
  !this.state.fullText ?

       <div onClick={() => this.setState({ fullText: !this.state.fullText })} 
       className="text-primary cursor-pointer font-size-14 mt-2 px-2"  
        key={props.data?.id}>
                Full Text 
        </div>
         :
         <>
       <div onClick={() => this.setState({ fullText: !this.state.fullText 
          })}className="text-primary cursor-pointer font-size-14 mt-2 px-2" 
          key={props.data?.id}>
                 Short Text 
       </div>
               <span>{ props.data?.caption}</span>
        </>
          }
```

Comment: "_all rows in the table are opened_": in your code sample, there is nothing that looks like a repetition of Elements, so it is difficult to tell exactly the issue. Obviously it seems like the toggle state needs to be aware of the clicked row, or the components could be organized differently (one state per row), depending on your exact need (only 1 open row at a time?)

Comment: If you could share a [mcve], it would be easier to provide a relevant answer.

Comment: here is my basic example about the problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ptolemy-rztuyo?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the code sample in the question is repeated for each row, but there is only 1 state `fullText` (`showMore` in the CodeSandbox) that is common for all these rows. Hence they all open or close together.

If you want individual open/close feature for each row, then you need 1 such state per row. An easy solution could be to embed this state with the data of each row:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        description: "aaaaa",
        showMore: false // Initially closed
      },
      // etc.
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.data.map((e) => (
          <>
            { /* Read the showMore state of the row, instead of a shared state */
              e.showMore === false ? (
              <div onClick={() => this.setState({ data: changeShow(this.state.data, e.id, true) })}>
                Show description{" "}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <>
                <div onClick={() => this.setState({ data: changeShow(this.state.data, e.id, false) })}>
                  Show less{" "}
                </div>
                <span key={e.id}>{e.description} </span>
              </>
            )}
          </>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Update the showMore property of the
 * row with the given id.
 */
function changeShow(data, id, show) {
  for (const row of data) {
    if (row.id === id) { // Find the matching row id
      row.showMore = show; // Update the property
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you think i can solve it with a better method using ref?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you have in mind exactly? Please feel free to open a new question to expose the details of your idea.

Comment: here is my solution https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-sea-3wo1zq?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

there are two specific desired outputs you might want. you can either make it open only one row at a time. you can also make them individual row specific to open or close independently.

For making specific row behave on its own you can store a list of ids in state for the expanded view and show the relevant component or behaviour.

```
class RowSpecific extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedIds: [],
      data: [
        { id: "1", otherInfo: {} },
        { id: "2", otherInfo: {} },
        { id: "3", otherInfo: {} },
      ],
    };
    this.handleExpandHide = this.handleExpandHide.bind(this);
  }
  handleExpandHide(expand, id) {
    if (!id) return;
    let sIds = [...this.state.selectedIds];
    if (expand) sIds.push(id);
    else sIds.remove((rId) => rId === id);
    this.setState({
      selectedIds: sIds,
    });
  }
  render() {
    let list = this.state.data.map((data) => {
      let show = this.state.selectedIds.find((id) => data.id === id);
      return show ? (
        <ExpandedView
          data={data}
          onExpandHide={(e) => {
            this.handleExpandHide(true, data.id);
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <CollapseView
          data={data}
          onExpandHide={(e) => {
            this.handleExpandHide(true, data.id);
          }}
        />
      );
    });
    return list;
  }
}
```

For making it open only one at a time you can save the clicked id in state and then when showing it only the matched id in state should be shown as open . rest are closed.

```
class SingleRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedId: "2",
      data: [
        { id: "1", otherInfo: {} },
        { id: "2", otherInfo: {} },
        { id: "3", otherInfo: {} },
      ],
    };
  }
  render() {
    let list = this.state.data.map((data) => {
      let show = data.id === this.state.selectedId;
      return show ? <ExpandedView data={data} /> : <CollapseView data={data} />;
    });
    return list;
  }
}
```